# Acumatica Exception- DiscTakenAcctID: 'Cash Discount Account' cannot be empty.; DiscTakenSubID: 'Cash Discount Sub.' cannot be empty."

Tags: api, rest, acumatica

```js
{
    "EmployeeID": {
        "value": "APAUTEST13"
    },
    "EmployeeName": {
        "value": "Tester Tester Tester, Miss"
    },
     
    "EmployeeSettings": {
        "BranchID": {
            "value": "MAIN"
        },
        
        "Calendar": {
            "value": "AUCALENDAR"
        },
        "CurrencyID": {
            "value": "AUD"
        },
        "DepartmentID": {
            "value": "FINANCE"
        },
        "EmployeeClass": {
            "value": "EMPLYDFT"
        },
        "EmployeeRefNbr": {},
        "EnableCurrencyOverride": {
            "value": true
        },
        "EnableRateOverride": {
            "value": true
        },
        "LaborItem": {},
        "RegularHoursValidation": {
            "value": "Warning Only"
        },
        "ReportsTo": null,
        "RouteEmails": {
            "value": true
        },
        "Salesperson": {},
        "TimeCardIsRequired": {
            "value": false
        },
        "custom": {}
    },
    "EmploymentHistory": [],
    "ExpenseAllocationSettings": {
        "AllocationMethod": {
            "value": "No Allocation"
        },
        "custom": {}
    },
    "FinancialSettings": {
        
        "APAccount": {
             "value": "63000"
        },
        "APSubaccount": {
             "value": "63000"
        },
        "CashAccount": {
           
            "value": "10100"
        },
        
        "ExpenseAccount": {
            "value": "63000"
        },
        "ExpenseSubaccount": {
            "value": "0"
        },
        "PaymentMethod": {
           
            "value": "AUANZDC"
        },
        "PrepaymentAccount": {
             "value": "63000"
        },
        "PrepaymentSubaccount": {
             "value": "63000"
        },
        "SalesAccount": {
            "value": "10"
        },
        "SalesSubaccount": {
            "value": "0"
        },
        
        "TaxZone": {
            "value": null
        },
        "Terms": {
            "value": "30THMONTH"
        },
        "PaymentInstructions": [
            {
                "PaymentInstructionsID": {
                    "value": 1
                },
                "Description": {
                    "value": "Account Number"
                },
                "PaymentMethod": {
                    "value": "AUANZDC"
                },
                "Value": {
                    "value": "985324978"
                }
            },
            {
                "PaymentInstructionsID": {
                    "value": 2
                },
                "Description": {
                    "value": "Title of Account"
                },
                "PaymentMethod": {
                    "value": "AUANZDC"
                },
                "Value": {
                    "value": "TestMiss"
                }
            },
            {
                "PaymentInstructionsID": {
                    "value": 3
                },
                "Description": {
                    "value": "BSB Number"
                },
                "PaymentMethod": {
                    "value": "AUANZDC"
                },
                "Value": {
                    "value": "048490"
                }
            }
        ],
        "custom": {}
    },
    "ContactInfo": {
        "Address": {
            "Country": {
                "value": "AU"
            }
        },
        "DateOfBirth": {
            "value": "1982-12-29T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "Email": {
            "value": "Tester.Test@myobap.com"
        },
        "Fax": {},
        "FaxType": {
            "value": "Home Fax"
        },
        "FirstName": {
            "value": "Tester"
        },
        "Gender": {
            "value": "Female"
        },
        "LastName": {
            "value": "Tester"
        },
        "MaritalStatus": {},
        "MiddleName": {
            "value": "Tester"
        },
        "Phone1": {},
        "Phone1Type": {
            "value": "Home"
        },
        "Phone2": {
            "value": "+ (68) 2 9804 8680"
        },
        "Phone2Type": {
            "value": "Cell"
        },
        "Phone3": {},
        "Phone3Type": {
            "value": "Business 1"
        },
        "SpousePartnerName": {},
        "Title": {
            "value": "Miss"
        },
        "Web": {}
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Active"
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the endpoint with this payload to add the employee payment instructions & getting this exception. I have verified the adhoc schema & using it in same format in the payload & getting this excption. The key value pair for **DiscTakenAcctID: 'Cash Discount Account'** & **DiscTakenSubID: 'Cash Discount Sub.'** does not exist in the schema definition for Payment insturctions.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried updating payload after comparing it with schema from documenation however it is not making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes for the field are:

```
    [Account(DisplayName = "Cash Discount Account", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, DescriptionField = typeof(Account.description))]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Select<EPEmployeeClass, Where<EPEmployeeClass.vendorClassID, Equal<Current<EPEmployee.vendorClassID>>>>), SourceField = typeof(EPEmployeeClass.discTakenAcctID))]
    public override Int32? DiscTakenAcctID { get; set; }
```

It states that it is pulled from the vendor fields, as EPEmployee is a vendor. The attribute states it pulls from the VendorClass. Cash Discount Account is a required field on the Employee Class record. I would make sure that "EMPLYDFT" is correct and has the cash discount account set properly.